JMeter WebDriver Sampler: "Invalid call sequence" error with Groovy script after upgrade to WebDriver 4.13.0.1
I'm using JMeter 5.6.3 with the WebDriver Sampler version 4.13.0.1 and Groovy for scripting. After upgrading to this version, I started encountering the following error:
2024-09-17 19:30:23,748 ERROR o.a.j.s.SampleResult:
   sampleStart called twice java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.sampleStart(SampleResult.java:1186)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:3)

Here’s a snippet of my Groovy code:
WDS.browser.manage().window().maximize()
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.log.info("Login page loading is started");
WDS.browser.get("${base_url}");
WDS.log.info("Login page is loaded");
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();

What could be causing this "Invalid call sequence" error in my current setup? Are there specific best practices or configurations I should follow to avoid this issue with the WebDriver Sampler in JMeter?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Feel free to adjust any details to better fit your situation!

It sounds like a bug in 4.13.0.1, you can report it and downgrade to 4.13.0.0 using JMeter Plugins Manager

It also worth reporting the issue via JMeter Plugins Support Forum

I upload jmx to redline13 for distributed testings. how it effect with readline13 webdriver?
